Chat history via teams js
I am developing Microsoft Teams app and is there way to get chat history/messages of teams group or one to one chat using teams js sdk (without using ms graph api)?
teams js - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/using-teams-client-library?tabs=javascript%2Cmanifest-teams-toolkit#whats-new-in-teamsjs-version-2xx
